# Fill in values with by clicking on a button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a bar button and by click a specific field should be filled. This should not be a big deal, but my field is in a uitable (cell). Is it possible to access and fill this field and by field I mean a text field?

The idea is to do something like this that I do for the table [image: table]

I have tired to do something similar but it does not really work... i really don't have a clue how to do it..

```
- (IBAction)btnOneToOne:(id)sender {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OrderCell";
    EntityOrderCell *cell;
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[EntityOrderCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    PoPositionObject *e;
    cell.lblReceivedQu.text = e.QuantityTbdl;

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Glitcher well not really a error it just doesn't to a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you should access the field in the UITableView directly. Instead you can have a flag in the ViewController, and when clicking a button, the flag will be updated. Then you can call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Or if you know the exact row, you can do

```
[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]
```

And then you can have the code in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: which will work depending on the flag.

Comment: so I just have to add this to my button method ?

Comment: "by click a specific field should be filled" - this should be done in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, e.g. if(buttonClicked) { someField.text = @"someValue" }. The only thing the button should do is to trigger the table or cell reload. When [self.tableView reloadData] is called it calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath for cells and the data in the cell is refreshed.

Comment: ooo see got it it works now I just use tags to see if the button was clicked ''^^!! thx allot

Answer (score 0):

Add this PoPositionObject information into your tableview's data source, and then change its value and call [table reloadData] on click.

Comment: what i said is to update your datasource and call [table reloadData]